# Generate Xml schema from c# classes

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I need to create a web-service that will integrate information from SAP within my organization. I have an existing application with a database structure. SAP will use the web-service to store values into the relevant tables/columns in the database.

For this, I need to provide the SAP team with an Xml schema that will be used to pass the data. Now, I do not know a lot about xml. What I did is I created Dto's based on the Entity Framework classes of all the relavent tables. This includes 8 different classes:
[image: RFQ Schema]

RFQ is the `base class` and it can contain either an RFQGoods or an RFQServices.

Next, I attempted using the xsd.exe tool to generate a schema, but received this result:

> Error: There was an error processing 'RfqService.dll'.
>     - There was an error reflecting type 'RfqService.DataTransferObjects.RfqDto'.
>     - Cannot serialize member 'RfqService.DataTransferObjects.RfqDto.RFQGoods' of
>   type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[RfqService.DataTransferObjects.RfqGoodDto, RfqService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', see inner exception for more details.
>     - Cannot serialize member RfqService.DataTransferObjects.RfqDto.RFQGoods of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[RfqService.DataTransferObjects.RfqGoodDto, RfqService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.

I think what I need is the correct xml `attributes` for the classes and each of their `parameters`, but I do not know what attributes I need to add to make this work and haven't been able to find out. Below is the RfqDto class:

```
[DataContract]
public class RfqDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int RfqId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsAbove30k { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ContactPersonName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ContactPersonTelephoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ContactPersonCellPhone { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BuyerName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BuyerTelephoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BuyerEmailAddress { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> QuotationBoxNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> FloorNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ProcurementItemDto ProcurementItem { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<RfqGoodDto> RfqGoods { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<RfqServiceDto> RfqServices { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `ICollection<T>` members to `List<T>`. The error you are getting is basically telling you that you can not serialize interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EntityFrameWork` for doing same.you have to add one `.edmx` file into your application and then you have to configure database and in Model you will find the schema of your database

more informatin you can refer link [EF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/19/absolue-beginners-guide-to-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I have a `.edmx` with the database schema. However, what I want is an `xml` schema file, `.xsd`